# Get the selected id from nested drop list jQuery and razor

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a sidebar that suppose when item clicked on it it change the constant of the page the problem seems that I can not get the selected item idea

My razor code:

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="lessons">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-toggle="collapse">
                @foreach (var chapter in Model)
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> @chapter.chapterName <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach (var lesson in chapter.Lessons)
                            {
                                <li value="@lesson.lessonsId"><a href="">@lesson.lessonsName</a></li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#lessons").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("getLesson")',
                    data: { Id: $('#lessons').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#theText').replaceWith(data.lessonsDescription);
                        $('#theVedio').attr('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.lessonsVedio);
                        $('#theVedio').load();
                    }
                })
            })

                $('#menu-toggle').click(function () {
                    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
                });

        });
```

The generated html markup for the sidebar:

```
   <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="lessons">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> primes <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li value="2"><a href="">primes factorization</a></li>
                                <li value="6"><a href="">primes 2</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> algorithims <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li value="9"><a href="">kmp</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your element with `id="lessons"` is a `<div>`, not an input - `.val()` gets the value of a form control (input, textarea, select)

Comment: And `value` is not a valid attribute for a `<li>` element

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you help me to fixed i have put it in form and change the ul into opgroup and the li into option still can not get the selected and it style all is gone

Comment: Its not even clear what your wanting to do since you code handles clicking on the `<div>`. I assume what you want to do is handle the click event of the inner  `<li>` elements and then pass the value of the associated `lessonsId`?

Comment: yes that is what i am tring to do

Comment: The its `<li data-id="@lesson.lessonsId">` in the view and `$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function() { var data = { Id: $(this).data('id') }; $.ajax({ .... data: data, ...`

Comment: thanks it works the id was send , althought i still have problem with the jqery it didn't change anything but thanks for the help

Comment: According to [W3C standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) the value attribute is deprecated and sets the number of the current list item. Use `data-value` or another `data-*` attribute to store custom data.